# Erro "no such file or directory" - Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, arm

Estou desenvolvendo um software em uma placa de protótipos, que é a ARMST32 - F411RE, para isso criei no software STM32CubeMX o seguinte modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao gerar o algoritmo e tentar visualizá-lo no Eclipse o seguinte erro me é exibido **No such file or directory**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EM outros computadores o software funcionou normalmente, e se inicio um projeto do zero o erro não ocorre. Pesquisei em inúmeros lugares porém nada conseguiu resolver o meu problema.

Comment: Poste o stacktrace de erro para que possamos ver melhor. 
Mas dá pra perceber que este erro é por causa de algum arquivo ou pasta faltante, que existia em outros computadores e no seu não, ou é referenciado em seu projeto em outro local. E qnd o projeto é criado do zero, ele deve criar automaticamente e referenciar em seu projeto corretamente.

Comment: e o arquivo **main.h** existe no diretório de trabalho?

Comment: @Wilker, Sou iniciante nessa linguagem, o que seria o `Stacktrace`

Comment: @Amadeus o **main.h** o `.h` seria o formato do arquivo?

Comment: Extensão do arquivo. Assim como um arquivo texto, tem a extensão .txt, normalmente

Comment: Seria toda a saída de erro que ocorre, ao invés de apenas um print da tela que mostra apenas uma parte do erro.

Comment: @Wilker poderia me dizer onde eu tenho acesso a toda a saída de erro? Para que eu possa alterar a questão

Comment: Depende da IDE, talvez seja ali onde está Erros(3). Ou em alguma outra aba dessa, qnd vc tenta rodar o projeto.

Com o eclispe eu não sou familiarizado.

Comment: Vou ver aqui e assim que possível atualizo a pergunta. Obrigado pelas dicas